# Arcpy.da.SearchCursor() help when attribute doesn't exist

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, cursor, table

I'm updating text elements off of an arcpy.da.SearchCursor script and needed to construct the script to return a response for when the attribute does NOT exist. Here is the snippet of the code **THAT WORKS**:

```
fcWO = r"W:\\GIS_Projects\\Impervious_Surfaces_Tables\\SUM_WORKORDER"
field1 = "SURFACE_TYPE"
field2 = "SUM_SQ_FT"

valueB = r"N/A"
valueM = r"N/A"
valueP = r"N/A"
valueS = r"N/A"
valueR = r"N/A"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fcWO, (field1, field2)) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == "BUILDING":
            valueB = row[1]
        elif row[0] == "MISC":
            valueM = row[1]
        elif row[0] == "PARKING":
            valueP = row[1]
        elif row[0] == "ROAD":
            valueR = row[1]
        elif row[0] == "SIDEWALK":
            valueS = row[1]

for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT"):
    if elm.name == 'Building':
        elm.text = valueB
    elif elm.name == 'Misc':
        elm.text = valueM
    elif elm.name == 'Parking':
        elm.text = valueP
    elif elm.name == 'Roadway':
        elm.text = valueR
    elif elm.name == 'Sidwalk':
        elm.text = valueS
```

Comment: I think you should focus your question on a code snippet that simply uses a text element alone on a layout to see if you can move a single value from a table into it. I would use a SearchCursor to read the table and pseudo-dynamic text to display it.

Comment: any reason for not using "view > report" ? Editing text element with Python will require a lot of "hard coding" ta achieve a nice layout.

Comment: @radouxju , Yes, you are correct. However, I'm trying to make something that other "less savvy" users can operate. I'm trying to eliminate as much "free-thought" as possible. :-) If all they have to do is enter in two values, and press one button, it will greatly reduces the potential for errors that currently exists in our workflow.

Comment: I think you should be using elif instead of else? What does `valueB = '{:,.0f}'.format((row[1]))` do?

Comment: @GISKid , I tried that and I couldn't quite get it to work. valueB should be the formatted number that is in row[1] of where row[0] == "BUILDING". Am I making sense? The end result is a pdf that has square footage of impervious surfaces. Instead of copying and pasting, I would like the script to calculate and place these values in certain spots on the layout (the text elements).

Comment: @LayneLeBleu that's really interesting. A visual example would help me, as i'm a visual learner. I think your indentation may be off, all your if and elif and elses should be in line with each other

Comment: @GISKid I feel like I have tried every way imaginable on indentation, however, it is very possible I have missed something. I added a screen shot of my map layout and the table that the cursor is "searching".

Comment: Your if/else doesn't make sense to me as is. Try something similar to this? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157459/creating-a-value-counting-table-with-search-and-update-cursor

Comment: You should use elif statements instead of all the if statements. It runs faster and is a nicer piece of programming. I changed my answer according to your wanted result. I hope it works fine with you now.

Comment: @Alex Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @GISKid thank you for your help. That link did help me construct some better arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue with your code sample:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
fc = r"W:\\GIS_Projects\\Impervious_Surfaces_Tables\\TOTAL"
field1 = "SURFACE_TYPE"
field2 = "SUM_SQ_FT"
value = ""

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [field1, field2]) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         if row[0] == "BUILDING":
              value = str(row[1])

for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT"):
     if elm.name == 'Total':
          elm.text = value

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

**THIS WORKS!**:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
fc = r"W:\\GIS_Projects\\Impervious_Surfaces_Tables\\TOTAL"
field1 = "SURFACE_TYPE"
field2 = "SUM_SQ_FT"

valueB = r"N/A"
valueM = r"N/A"
valueP = r"N/A"
valueS = r"N/A"
valueR = r"N/A"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (field1, field2)) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         if row[0] == "BUILDING":
              valueB = str(row[1]
         elif row[0] == "MISC":
              valueM = str(row[1]
         elif row[0] == "PARKING":
              valueP = str(row[1]
         elif row[0] == "ROAD":
              valueR = str(row[1]
         elif row[0] == "SIDEWALK":
              valueS = str(row[1]

for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT"):
    if elm.name == 'Building':
        elm.text = valueB
    elif elm.name == 'Misc':
        elm.text = valueM
    elif elm.name == 'Parking':
        elm.text = valueP
    elif elm.name == 'Roadway':
        elm.text = valueR
    elif elm.name == 'Sidewalk':
        elm.text = valueS

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

If you print the map after you refresh it I would suggest to set all the text elements back to "N/A". It would be the same code as above, just with

> elm.text = r"N/A"

Comment: I attempted the above code. I tweaked it to match my table and element name. However, when I run it, I receive this error:

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
RuntimeError: An invalid SQL statement was used.

Comment: @Layne LeBleu: Sorry I am not that familiar wirth the da.cursors. The fields need to be in square brackets (line 9 / old script line 6). And there is no getvalue and setvalue. I changed the script accordingly and tested it. It works now.

Comment: no worries! I JUST figured that out and came here to edit my comment. However, do I need to reset the cursor after it names each element? When I run the script, it will give the value correctly for the first two, and then the final entry.

Comment: It depends on what you really want to do. If you want to work with differnet conditions, I would suggest to work with one cursor only. If you want to have a dummy variable, or an empty text you need to specify that. I added an alternative script for that to my answer. Is that what you meant?

Comment: We are SO close! I updated the code in the question. It has has everything working EXCEPT that "BUILDING" AND "PARKING" are not working correctly. The only value that should return a "N/A" should be "ROADWAY" which is working properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works brilliantly! I just had to change a few things which I'll do in your answer. Using parentheses instead of brackets for the field names, and the element names are case sensitive.

Comment: I was premature. It doesn't update the "N/A" but...if I start with a "template" map that already has the "N/A"'s, it still works if a certain value doesn't exist.

Comment: That is strange. It works in my test mxd. However, it works with both, brackets and parentheses, in my mxd, too. Sorry I cannot help you there. Did you try to first set all text to "N/A" in the beginning of the script? This way you don't have to change your mxd every time.

Comment: I thought it was strange too. I have it so the user just closes the map without saving. That way when it is reopened, all of the "N/A"s are there.